# Outlook 2010 Category search

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, macros, vba

I am looking for a script for Outlook 2010 Categories that will act like Evernote tags. Once you start typing in a search bar it will start displaying the categories that match.

Is there something that already exists or could point me in the right direction?